# Angular - Spring Boot - Nginx - Login Popup

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have setup Angular and Spring boot with Spring Security.

Angular apps calls the backend api using Nginx reverse proxy and I am passing authentication in Nginx settings as headers.

When i hit the url, browser keeps asking asking for username and password, when I am trying to load the data through browser.

Any suggestions how to solve this issue.

attached screenshot.

Thanks,
Vijay.

Comment: You should add more information. How are you passing user and password? How is working your security in spring boot? How do you configured nginx? I suggest to go step by step, in order to find where is the error.

Comment: @georgeos Thanks for responding. I am passing username and password in Nginx reverse proxy as header. I am new to springboot, i just added spring security in pom.xml and setup login and password in application. properties